# How to export multi level mat grid to excel in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an example where I have multi level material grid data . I want to download it to an excel .

The problem is i am able to export only the 1st level of data . The expanded rows data are coming from different API's based on the id of the row selected .

How can I export all the level of data hierarchically to excel ?

Code i used for exporting the 1st level -

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export class TableUtil {
  static exportToExcel(tableId: string, name?: string) {
    let timeSpan = new Date().toISOString();
    let prefix = name || "ExportResult";
    let fileName = `${prefix}-${timeSpan}`;
    let targetTableElm = document.getElementById(tableId);
    let wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm, <XLSX.Table2SheetOpts>{ sheet: prefix });
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
  }
}
```

My [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-bpvhfr?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) Link for my material grid in action -

Answer (score 1):

The export function seems correct. All you need is to call a method before the export function, which will populate all the expanded rows.
Something like this.

1. Declare an array of observable.
2. Loop the parent table, and create an observable to get the inner table data. Do not subscribe to the observable here. Just add the observable to the array.
3. After the loop, using rxjs operator, combineLatest. It will call all the observable parallelly. You can subscribe to this and invoke your excel method.